# This request requires elevation

Tags: port, netstat

I am trying to list my ports on Windows using the **netstat -a -b** but I am getting this error :

> This request requires elevation

I have tried to solve this by taking my laptop up to the roof level of my flat complex (10th floor) , and running the command there but it doesn't seem to work either.

Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried taking it into an airplane? If that doesn't work you can now buy a seats on space-bound flights. Another more boring and inexpensive alternative is run the command with administrator privileges.

Comment: Another way is to ask the International Space Station to remote in and run the command for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run ***netstat -b*** you have to run the command prompt with administrator privileges.

Alternatively you can use PowerShell without admin elevation to view ports:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection
```

or a specific state:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen
```

or even more specific:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen,Established
```